# Normal distribution of juice

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, standard-deviation

Quantity of juice in a pack of 1L is normaly distributed with average (mean) 950ml, and with standard deviation of 10ml.

What is the probability that random pack of juice contains less then 945ml of juice?

Comment: If the mean is 950, then the deviation doesn't matter. Half the data will be below the mean.

Comment: @eddybob123 I appologize, i made a typo. I corrected the question now.

Comment: Could you show us the work you've already done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$945$ mL is $5$ mL below the mean.  $5$ mL is half of the standard deviation.  So the question is, what is the probability that a standard normal random variable is less than $-1/2\ {}$?  Usually you'll get that from a table or from software.

Comment: Thanks. So it should be z=-0.5, so the probability is 0.3805 right?

Comment: Yes. ${}\qquad{}$